# jQuery Sorting and Filtering Multiple Columns

Tags: jquery, sorting, filtering

I want to be able to sort and filter multiple columns using a jquery plugin.

Does anyone know of any that will do this?

The following example is very close to what i want except it doesn't do multiple sorts http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-key.html

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

in both cases you will have to use a special key when using multiple column sorting